# File.separator returns wrong value in Java

Tags: java, macos

So, in my Java project, it's all ready to go and compiled. The only problem is that File.separator returns "\" instead of "/" on my Mac, which results in a misformed file path.

The code is something like this: `"files" + File.separator + "PDF.png"` which returns `files\pdf.png` when it should be `files/pdf.png`

How do I fix this? Preferably without compiling the .jar again. Is there a way to change File.separator systemwide or through Terminal?

Comment: Try upgrading/re-installing Java. I do not have this problem with Java 1.7.0_45 on OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: Try giving us actual code.  Where was it compiled, that you don't want to do that again?